# SQLite having clause requires group by, but I don't need a group by

Tags: android, sqlite

Experts,

Here is my goal:

get the value of A from a query, where B=max(B), if the query return 0 row, then set 999999.

If use Method 1, syntax error because no group by clause, but I don't need a group.

If use Method 2, when CONDITIONS are false, namely 0 row, the cursor.getCount() ==1 >0, cannot get 999999.

One way I can think of is add a column C set value 'constant' in tb, then add group by C in Method 1.
But it is totally not grace.

What should I do? Thanks.

Method 1:

```
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select A, B " +
            "from tb " +
            "where "CONDITIONS" + 
            "having B=max(B)", null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    valueA = cursor.getDouble(0);  
    if (cursor.getCount()==0) valueA = 999999;
    cursor.close();
```

Method 2:

```
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select A, max(B) " +
            "from tb " +
            "where "CONDITIONS", null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    valueA = cursor.getDouble(0);  
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) valueA = 999999;
    cursor.close();
```

Comment: having clause always requires a GROUP BY http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_having_clause.htm

Comment: what is the CONDITIONS variable?

Comment: I disagree marked as duplicate. I aware having requires group by. I am looking a grace way to combine condition logic and cursor-query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should place the 'max(b)' function in the select clause, because this is the best way to find the aggregate.
2. You will get at least one row in the resulting cursor even if the values are NULL. So, you should read the value of 'max(b)' from the cursor and then add the logic.

Comment: when the query got 0 row, max(b) is 0 then I can use it to add logic. But what if query got rows and max(b) IS 0? How to tell which 0 is which?

Comment: You can add an additional column: count(B)

Comment: sounds wonderful, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In your first method, you are using the keyword having which is used with the GROUP BY keyword. So the code is giving you the error.

Having keyword example:

```
SELECT * FROM Students GROUP BY name HAVING count(name) < 2;
```

You can use following command:

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name where MAX(column_name);
```

and:

```
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount()<1){
    valueA= 999999;
    }else{
     valueA= cursor.getDouble(0);  
    }
    cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If use group function you must use group by .

### You can use sub query like this ..

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select A , B " +
        "from tb " +
        "where "CONDITIONS" + 
        " AND B = (select max(B) from tb)", null);
```

Comment: I think there is a logic problem. Imaging I have a tb with 3 column X={true true false} and Y={2,5,7} and Z={1,2,3}.  When the where CONDITIONS is X=true, and HAVING is Y=max(Y), I hope to get Z=2. But your statement would get 0 row. (X=true and Y=7)

Comment: AND B = (select max(B) from tb where "CONDITIONS") would work, but CONDITIONS are very complicate, wirte it twice seems not a grace statement.

Comment: what is your "CONDITIONS" i don't know.......give it than .....i will try to solve ...

Comment: It doesn't matter about the CONDITIONS, it is a logic problem.